# I'm stuck in Adsense Approval Limbo

Tags: google-adsense

More than likely I've screwed myself tremendously here -- but if anyone has any advice on what I can do to fix this, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Here's my scenario:

- Gmail account A:

  - My normal, personal Gmail account.
  - Has a YouTube channel, that is monetized (with just about zero views). Not sure why I monetized it.
  - "Hosted" Adsense account.
  - This is the email used for Google's Webmaster Tools, for my new domain.
  - Under Adsense's "My Sites", my domain I'm trying to put Adsense on now is listed as verified. (likely due to the Webmaster Tools).
- Gmail account B:

  - This account was created to provide an email address for the users of my site to contact for support.

When I went to create an Adsense account for the site, I mistakenly used Gmail account B. It's been sitting at "Reviewing" for a few weeks now, and I'm fearing a rejection. I figured I'd go in to my *real* account and try to add it there, but when I go to My Ads -> Other Products, it redirects me back to the Adsense home page.

So, I think I broke something. Any advice, or input, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The redirect issue is actually a wide-issue that affects several Google services. You need completely log out and clear the browser cache entirely including cookies, then try again.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks for the suggestion! In Chrome, I signed out of Adsense, deleted everything (except for History) since "The beginning of Time", closed the app, verified there were no Chrome's running (`ps -aux | grep -i chrome`), re-opened and tried again. I still get the redirect issue. :(

Comment: Maybe try a different browser, I get a redirect when attempting to login to Google My Business & Google Analyics, it has something to do with 'add account'.

Comment: @SimonHayter I tried it in IE as well before posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was just impatient. Woke up this morning to "*Congratulations!
Your account is now fully approved.*" from Google on my Account B.

Thanks for all of your help!